# how can i set location of buttons in winphone 8

Tags: c#, layout, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I change `Button`'s `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, all the other Buttons' locations change too. I want the `Buttons` to stay in their original locations.
(btn.location produced an error & did not work)

This is my code :

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    Button btn = new Button();
    {
      btn.Name = "Btn" + i.ToString();
      btn.Height = 100;
      btn.Width = 100;
      btn.Content = "0";
      btn.Margin = new Thickness(y, x, 0, 0);
      btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    btns[i] = btn;
    stkpanel.Children.Add(btn);
    i++;
  }
  x -= 700;
  y += 200;
}
ContentPanel.Children.Add(stkpanel);
```

Comment: Try `Visibility.Hidden` and see what happens.  Also, when asking about "my code that does XYZ doesn't work" show your XYZ code, not some random code from your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a trick instead of setting Visibility to Collapsed, set the buttons opacity to 0 and IsEnabled to false.

```
btn.Opacity = 0;
btn.IsEnabled = false;
```